# AS3: Reusing URLLoader, URLRequest, and URLVariables instances

Tags: actionscript-3, optimization, actionscript

My Flash project uses URLLoader.load a lot to load content from a web server and post to a php page. Should I reuse my URLLoader, URLRequest, and URLVariables instances, or should I create new ones each time? If I should create new ones each time, do the old ones need to be disposed of somehow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should most certainly never ever ever reuse any instances related to external operations and you should thoroughly dispose of them the very moment you don't need them. The overhead of Garbage Collector (GC) working on these objects is literally nothing next to the nightmare mess you might get into once your external operations collide via sharing the same operational instances.

**URLVariables** and **URLRequest** do not need any special treatment, just set **null** to any variables referencing them and ensure that method, where they were assigned to local variables, do not produce any function closures. Well, set **URLRequest.data** to **null** to break this reference.

**URLLoader**, on the other hand, needs to be pushed around a bit:

1. If **URLLoader.data** is a **ByteArray**, then you should **ByteArray.clear()** it (unless you need it).
2. Set the **URLLoader.data** to **null**.
3. Initially subscribe all error handlers with weak references (fifth argument of **addEventListener** set to **true**) and don't unsubscribe them. Weak keys won't affect the GCs judgement while keeping the subscriptions might save you from occasional *Unhandled Error Event* case.
4. Certainly do unsubscribe all non-error handlers.
5. In all the handlers, first check if **Event.target** is a valid **URLLoader** instance to avoid handling an event from a dead/disposed **URLLoader**.
6. Call **URLLoader.close()** just in case. Yes, after all of above is done.

Below is the class I use to load things in a simple way. It is built on the same principles I listed above. It allows loading text/binary data and also provides some proof against unstable network: you can set the **repeatCount** argument to higher values to provide fail-safe loading if you know that requests tend to fail **sometimes**.

**Usage**:

```
// Load binary data over unstable network.
DataFiles.load("data.dat", onData, true, 10);

// Load XML file as text over a stable network or from the local storage.
DataFiles.load("setup.xml", onSetup);

function onData(source:ByteArray):void
{
    if (!source)
    {
        // Loading failed. Error case.
    }
    else
    {
        // File is loaded normally.
    }
}

function onSetup(source:String):void
{
    try
    {
        var aSetup:XML = new XML(source);

        // Process loaded XML normally.
    }
    catch (fail:Error)
    {
        // The source is either null or an invalid XML string.
        // Loading is failed, basically. Error case.
    }
}
```

**Implementation**:

```
package simplify
{
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.events.IOErrorEvent;

    import flash.net.URLLoader;
    import flash.net.URLRequest;
    import flash.net.URLLoaderDataFormat;

    public class DataFiles
    {
        static private var list:Vector.<DataFiles> = new Vector.<DataFiles>;

        static public function load(url:String, handler:Function, binary:Boolean = false, repeatCount:int = 1):void
        {
            var aLoader:DataFiles = new DataFiles;

            aLoader.url = url;
            aLoader.binary = binary;
            aLoader.handler = handler;
            aLoader.repeatCount = repeatCount;

            list.push(aLoader);
            aLoader.start();
        }

        private var url:String;
        private var binary:Boolean;
        private var handler:Function;

        private var loader:URLLoader;

        private var repeatCount:int;

        private function start():void
        {
            loader = new URLLoader;

            if (binary) loader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.BINARY;

            loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onComplete);
            loader.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, onError, false, 0, true);

            loader.load(new URLRequest(url));
        }

        private function destroyLoader():void
        {
            if (!loader) return;

            loader.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onComplete);

            var aDead:Loader = loader;

            loader = null;

            aDead.data = null;
            aDead.close();
        }

        private function onComplete(e:Event):void
        {
            if (e.target != loader) return;

            var aResult:* = loader.data;
            var aHandler:Function = handler;

            destroy();
            destroyLoader();
            aHandler(aResult);
        }

        private function onError(e:IOErrorEvent):void
        {
            if (e.target != loader) return;

            destroyLoader();
            repeatCount--;

            if (repeatCount >= 0)
            {
                start();
            }
            else
            {
                var aHandler:Function = handler;

                destroy();
                aHandler(null);
            }
        }

        private function destroy():void
        {
            var anIndex:int = list.indexOf(this);
            if (anIndex > -1) list.splice(anIndex, 1);

            handler = null;
            url = null;
        }
    }
}
```